# Sidebar doesn't work in Semantic UI. What should I do?

Tags: semantic-ui

I copied the menu example provided from the Sementic UI website into Visual Studio Code and tried running it as it is, but JS doesn't work.
As described on the website, the sidebar should appear when you click the menu button.
css, jQuery, sementic.min.js are all set through CDN. I entered the JS Code from the Console in Chrome DevTools, but it says'Uncaught TypeError: $(...).sidebar is not a function at :2:3'.

```js
$('.context.example .ui.sidebar')
    .sidebar({
        context: $('.context.example .bottom.segment'),
    })
    .sidebar('attach events', '.context.example .menu .item');
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Semantic UI</title>
        <link
            rel="stylesheet"
            href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.4.1/semantic.min.css"
            integrity="sha512-8bHTC73gkZ7rZ7vpqUQThUDhqcNFyYi2xgDgPDHc+GXVGHXq+xPjynxIopALmOPqzo9JZj0k6OqqewdGO3EsrQ=="
            crossorigin="anonymous"
            referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
        />
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script
            src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.4.1/semantic.min.js"
            integrity="sha512-dqw6X88iGgZlTsONxZK9ePmJEFrmHwpuMrsUChjAw1mRUhUITE5QU9pkcSox+ynfLhL15Sv2al5A0LVyDCmtUw=="
            crossorigin="anonymous"
            referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
        ></script>

        <script src="/main.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="ui top attached demo menu">
            <a class="item">
                <i class="sidebar icon"></i>
                Menu
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="ui bottom attached segment pushable">
            <div class="ui inverted labeled icon left inline vertical sidebar menu">
                <a class="item">
                    <i class="home icon"></i>
                    Home
                </a>
                <a class="item">
                    <i class="block layout icon"></i>
                    Topics
                </a>
                <a class="item">
                    <i class="smile icon"></i>
                    Friends
                </a>
                <a class="item">
                    <i class="calendar icon"></i>
                    History
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="pusher">
                <div class="ui basic segment">
                    <h3 class="ui header">Application Content</h3>
                    <p></p>
                    <p></p>
                    <p></p>
                    <p></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
$('.context.example .ui.sidebar')
.sidebar({
    context: $('.context.example .bottom.segment'),
})
.sidebar('attach events', '.context.example .menu .item');
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `.context.example` from the script then it will work. But you may see another problem, the main application segment creates unknown padding with respect to the sidebar menu.

```js
$('.ui.sidebar')
.sidebar({
    context: $('.bottom.segment'),
})
.sidebar('attach events', '.menu .item');
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Semantic UI</title>
        <link
            rel="stylesheet"
            href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.4.1/semantic.min.css"
            integrity="sha512-8bHTC73gkZ7rZ7vpqUQThUDhqcNFyYi2xgDgPDHc+GXVGHXq+xPjynxIopALmOPqzo9JZj0k6OqqewdGO3EsrQ=="
            crossorigin="anonymous"
            referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
        />
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script
            src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.4.1/semantic.min.js"
            integrity="sha512-dqw6X88iGgZlTsONxZK9ePmJEFrmHwpuMrsUChjAw1mRUhUITE5QU9pkcSox+ynfLhL15Sv2al5A0LVyDCmtUw=="
            crossorigin="anonymous"
            referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
        ></script>

        <script src="/main.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="ui top attached demo menu">
            <a class="item">
                <i class="sidebar icon"></i>
                Menu
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="ui bottom attached segment pushable">
            <div class="ui inverted labeled icon left inline vertical sidebar menu">
              
                <a class="item">
                    <i class="home icon"></i>
                    Home
                </a>
                <a class="item">
                    <i class="block layout icon"></i>
                    Topics
                </a>
                <a class="item">
                    <i class="smile icon"></i>
                    Friends
                </a>
                <a class="item">
                    <i class="calendar icon"></i>
                    History
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="pusher">
                <div class="ui basic segment">
                    <h3 class="ui header">Application Content</h3>
                    <p></p>
                    <p></p>
                    <p></p>
                    <p></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

To remove this unnecessary padding from the application segment i will suggest to change `<div class="ui inverted labeled icon left inline vertical sidebar menu">` to `<div class="ui inverted left vertical sidebar menu">`

```js
$('.ui.sidebar')
.sidebar({
    context: $('.bottom.segment'),
})
.sidebar('attach events', '.menu .item');
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Semantic UI</title>
        <link
            rel="stylesheet"
            href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.4.1/semantic.min.css"
            integrity="sha512-8bHTC73gkZ7rZ7vpqUQThUDhqcNFyYi2xgDgPDHc+GXVGHXq+xPjynxIopALmOPqzo9JZj0k6OqqewdGO3EsrQ=="
            crossorigin="anonymous"
            referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
        />
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script
            src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.4.1/semantic.min.js"
            integrity="sha512-dqw6X88iGgZlTsONxZK9ePmJEFrmHwpuMrsUChjAw1mRUhUITE5QU9pkcSox+ynfLhL15Sv2al5A0LVyDCmtUw=="
            crossorigin="anonymous"
            referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
        ></script>

        <script src="/main.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="ui top attached demo menu">
            <a class="item">
                <i class="sidebar icon"></i>
                Menu
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="ui bottom attached segment pushable">
            <div class="ui inverted left vertical sidebar menu">
              
                <a class="item">
                    <i class="home icon"></i>
                    Home
                </a>
                <a class="item">
                    <i class="block layout icon"></i>
                    Topics
                </a>
                <a class="item">
                    <i class="smile icon"></i>
                    Friends
                </a>
                <a class="item">
                    <i class="calendar icon"></i>
                    History
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="pusher">
                <div class="ui basic segment">
                    <h3 class="ui header">Application Content</h3>
                    <p></p>
                    <p></p>
                    <p></p>
                    <p></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

***NB:*** You should use your script tag in the bottom section of your code. Avoid initiating script in the head section.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        ............
    </head>
    <body>
        ............

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.4.1/semantic.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The code works good as per your advice. Thank you so much for providing additional explanations about unnecessary padding on that as well!